# E/SchedPolicy: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted

Tags: java, android

On an activity that uses:

```
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.2'
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.2'
```

In the logcat I see this:
`E/SchedPolicy: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted`

**I already tried:**

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: same issue..have you find any solution ?

Comment: I also have same issue did you finish the solution?